# Android homescreen shortcut permission error

Tags: java, android, shortcut, permissions, homescreen

In my program it adds a shortcut to the screen. I get the icon on the screen fine, but when I tap it, I get:

```
03-01 20:00:29.410: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(796): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { data=http://www.example.com/ flags=0x14000000 comp={com.isaacwaller.example/com.isaacwaller.example.ExampleCut} } from ProcessRecord{435c7398 796:android.process.acore/10005} (pid=796, uid=10005) requires null
```

Do you know the problem? Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out, added this under `<activity>` tag of activity:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 11):

I had something like this happen when I had accidentally duplicated the activity tag for one of my activities in my manifest.  I had something like this in my application section.

```
<activity android:name=".ConventionHome" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="ConventionHome"></activity>
```

When I removed the second activity tag, things started working normally.

Comment: This just fixed my error as well when I got "Application is not installed on this phone". I was following some examples from a book and didn't notice my copy and paste issue with the duplicate activity. nice catch! (Would be even nicer for: duplicate activity in manifest)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.Project.Action"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

inside of the Activity declaration in the manifest.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem too, and it turned out it was because the Activity wasn't exposed to other processes. I had to add the android:exported="true" attribute to the activity tag in my manifest.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't run into this personally but I did do some research and found the following.

Apparently whatever is attempting to invoke your app or if your app has a call to create an intent and start an activity of some intent the UID is not the same.

In ActivityManagerServer.java there are below judgement in it.

```
int checkComponentPermission(String permission, int pid, int uid, int reqUid)
// If the target requires a specific UID, always fail for others.
   if (reqUid >= 0 && uid != reqUid) {
       return PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
   }
```

I'm going to do some testing on this and see if I can reproduce this in a test application and provide any additional feedback.

Make sure you are only trying to invoke publicly exposed activities through any intents.