# Getting: Not allowed to start service Intent ... without permission Service process is bad

Tags: android, service, permissions

ACRA's crush report sends me this error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=auto_update cmp=net.DailyTimer.CalendarAlarmHelperFree/net.DailyTimer.CalendarAlarmHelper.CalendarAlarmService } without permission Service process is bad
```

I see this error on limited devices and I can't reproduce. I guess this error depends on running environment.
My question is:

- What permission is wrong? I could not find out what "Service process is bad" mean.

**EDIT:**
I'm getting this error when calling startService(intent) to start remote service. And on many devices it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Although I have not experienced this myself, I did some looking around and I think these might be useful to you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent), user Jomia says:

> The java.lang.SecurityException you are seeing is because you may
>   enter two entries pointing to same activity. Remove the second one and
>   you should be good to go.

Also, consider taking a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), specifically under `public static final int CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE`. Here is the relevant part:

> Setting this flags imposes security restrictions on what application
>   context you can access; if the requested application can not be safely
>   loaded into your process, java.lang.SecurityException will be thrown.
>   If this flag is not set, there will be no restrictions on the packages
>   that can be loaded, but getClassLoader() will always return the
>   default system class loader.

I hope I could be of some help. If these responses are unrelated to your issue, you might want to try posting relevant code, etc. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think given 2 links are not related to my problem. I edited question. My problem is related to startService.

Answer (score 0):

see Source code Line 10494，if method "**bringUpServiceLocked**" return false, it would throw "Service process is bad" Exception

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked%28com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked code you linked but I could not find out what caused the error nor solution for it.