# Permission Denial: starting Intent from null (pid=30992, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10142

Tags: android, apk, adb, alljoyn

While running a apk file (AllSeenValidation14.12.00b.02.apk) in adb shell, I am getting this eror message:

```
Command to run : adb shell am start org.alljoyn.validation.validation_tests.validation_tests_it/org.alljoyn.validation.testing.instrument.ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity
```

Error:

```
"Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 > cmp=org.alljoyn.validation.validation_tests.validation_tests_it/org.alljoyn.validation.testing.instrument.ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity } from null (pid=30992, uid=2000) not exported from  uid 10142 "   error.
```

Note: I don't have the source code of apk file (AllSeenValidation14.12.00b.02.apk)

Comment: You can't run an Activity not listed in the Manifest except from the app's user id.  Probably you weren't supposed to do this, or else the author got it wrong.  If it is a debug apk you can try run-as.  I don't know if it would work on a rooted device or emulator, as it is Android and not Linux doing the enforcing, but you could try.

Comment: This Activity(ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity) is listed in Manifest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android-permission-denied-error-when-changing-launcher-activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056214/android-permission-denied-error-when-changing-launcher-activity)

Comment: which permission caused the exception?

Comment: I don't have source code here different scenario from   [android-permission-denied-error-when-changing-launcher-activity]  @ asgs

Comment: If you don't have the source, how do you know for a fact that it is in the manifest?  It seems your question is incomplete without that evidence.

Comment: By using "aapt dump xmltree <apk-file> AndroidManifest.xml"  this command i got to know the Manifest file.
One of the line in Manifest file:
E: activity (line=38)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)="org.alljoyn.validation.testing.instrument.ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity" (Raw: "org.alljoyn.validation.testing.instrument.ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity")  @chris stratton

Comment: But does it have an intent filter?  If it lacks that or anything *explicitly* exporting it, you cannot launch it directly in the manner of a "deep link" but must rather launch something else which is exported first.  I continue to suspect that you are either not using this as intended, or else the author made a mistake.

Comment: Yes you are correct author made a mistake. I tried with previous version of APK it is working fine. Thank you Chris Stratton

Answer (score 5):

Here Notice `android:exported="true"`  this allowed activity to access outside of application example other app Or you can put  Intent Filter in same activity that need to access

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

This allow to open the

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In your example ValidationInstrumentationTestActivity Activity doesn't have android:exported=true  or intent-filter thats why you get "Permission Denial: starting Intent exception

I know this is not the answer but it help you to get what you want