# Android permission denial

Tags: android, permissions

I try to launch third-party app from my main activity:

intent = new Intent();

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.mojang.minecraftpe", 
"com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainMenuOptionsActivity");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I get error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22330): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission     Denial: starting  
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAINcmp=com.mojang.minecraftpe/.MainMenuOptionsActivity
} from ProcessRecord{407b6928 22330:com.metalex.musicplayer/10073} (pid=22330, uid=10073) 
requires null
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(class name.this, Activity2.class);      
    startActivity(i);

Comment: @shanthi: he wrote "third-party app" so he doesn't have access to `ThirdPartyActivity.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Intent intent= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mojang.minecraftpe");
startActivity(intent);
```

This way you don't have to figure out which activity you can launch.

Answer (score 2):

The rootcause is that the target activity is not exported, so there is no way to launch it from other apps.

Regards

Ziteng Chen