# Android: java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown package com.my.package

Tags: android

User's crash report sends me this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.youdao.dict.DictApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown package com.youdao.dict
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3377)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:155)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1031)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I see this error on limited devices and I can't reproduce.

My question is:
**What permission is wrong?**

Comment: @Syan please check this link once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent

Comment: @chintan my package name is com.youdao.dict

Comment: @Androholic it doesnt help me :(

Comment: check all files with manifest having same pkg name or ever change ?

Comment: yeah,i have checked...And i used eclipse and ADT, if i write two entries pointing to same activity, Android Lint will mark it fatal

Comment: did declared any permission in your manifest. Like read_storage, write_storage etc...