# Testing Android Fragments

Tags: android, junit, android-fragments

I have a business logic in UI-less fragment which I have to test. I have tried 2 options and both have failed.

**1. Use AndroidTestCase and create mock activity.**

Following code

```
@Override
protected void setUp() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getTestContext(), TestActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getTestContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

throws an exception

```
Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10104
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.xxx.iabsample.test/.TestActivity } from ProcessRecord{40769510 28116:com.xxx.iabsample/10070  (pid=28116, uid=10070) requires null
```

**2. Use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 with mock activity**

Code

```
public class IabTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TestActivity> {
    public IabTest() {
        super("com.xxx.iabsample.test", TestActivity.class);
    }
}
```

throws an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.xxx.iabsample/.test.TestActivity }
```

It seems that it tries to start activity from test-target app, not from the test app.

So, what is the correct way to test fragments?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent

Answer (score -2):

```
//Please try to use bellow code.


// activity layout  main.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/number_list"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/the_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.fragmenttest.TestFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

//Fragments java class.



 public class TestFragment extends Fragment

{

    private int nAndroids;

    public TestFragment() {

    }

   /**
    * Constructor for being created explicitly
    */
   public TestFragment(int nAndroids) {
        this.nAndroids = nAndroids;
    }

    /**
     * If we are being created with saved state, restore our state
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
        if (null != saved) {
            nAndroids = saved.getInt("nAndroids");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save the number of Androids to be displayed
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave) {
        toSave.putInt("nAndroids", nAndroids);
    }

    /**
     * Make a grid and fill it with n Androids
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
        int n;
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(c);
        for (n = 0; n < nAndroids; n++) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(c);
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
            l.addView(i);
            TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(-50, 30, 0, 0);
            a.setDuration(1000);

            l.startAnimation(a);
            a.setFillAfter(true);
        }
        return l;
    }
}

// Activity


public class FragmentTestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.number_list);
        ArrayAdapter numbers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                new String [] {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"
        });
        l.setAdapter(numbers);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    /**
     * Add a Fragment to our stack with n Androids in it
     */
    private void stackAFragment(int nAndroids) {
        Fragment f = new TestFragment(nAndroids);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.the_frag, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Called when a number gets clicked
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        stackAFragment(position + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this reply has anything to do with android test framework. Mind post some explanations along with the code?