# Start an sub class of an application from another application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried all the examples in SO and they do not work for me.  I wish to start a specific class in another application (not main) from inside my application.

I can start the application main page with this code (this works but not the class I want):

```
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.paloaltophoto.starttimer");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

But when I follow the examples from other SO answers to try and get to the class I want, I get an error

```
public void onTest(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.paloaltophoto.starttimer", "com.paloaltophoto.starttimer.edit"));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

I get a message about com.paloaltophoto.starttimer/com.paloaltophoto.starttimer.edit not being declared in my manifest but the manifest has this code:

```
   <activity android:name="com.paloaltophoto.starttimer.edit">
   </activity>
```

Everything complies fine.  Obviously the other application allows me to launch it as I can start it just fine on the main page but I can't find any reference on how I should make this work for a specific class.

Comment: Can you post the complete Class file?

Comment: I edited my question to include the entire view that I want to launch the other application.  I think that is what you want.  The rest of the file is large and likely irrelevant.

Comment: Did you try: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);`

Comment: I changed the first Intent line to the one suggested and it still crashes.

Comment: declare a unique action for your edid activity in your manifest and create an intent with that action

Comment: post your manifest file...i think it may be because of wrong package name make sure that correct package name is declared or not as <manifest
    package="com.paloaltophoto.starttimer"

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paloaltophoto.starttimer"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

Comment: What exactly should I declare in the manifest from the main application, which is called <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paloaltophoto.startline"

Answer (score 0):

The class is defined as:

```
ComponentName(package, activity_name)
```

So, from your comments, you need:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.paloaltophoto.startline", "com.paloaltophoto.starttimer.edit"));
```

because your package is name is different from your component path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run another activity from another application you should call:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(requiredPackage, requiredClazz));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code can throw:

- [ActivityNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html)
- SecurityException - called application should have [android:exported=true](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) to avoid this exception (more info in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent)).