# How to fix ussd code error?

Tags: android, ussd

My Logcat:

```
08-23 01:32:12.806    1299-1299/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.haftasia.easycode, PID: 1299
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{43f9a738 1299:com.haftasia.easycode/u0a181} (pid=1299, uid=10181) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2109)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3442)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3403)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3645)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3613)
            at com.haftasia.easycode.Day_3G_Mci$1$1.onClick(Day_3G_Mci.java:52)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4448)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18461)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this permission in your AppManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Your error occurred because you didn't add it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the logcat is saying everything what you looking for why dont you try to add permission ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an intent which makes an call but however for any app to make a call it requires the permission.

To add it in the Manifest before the application tag add the following

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```