# Android wifi state change - java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 10072

Tags: android, permissions, wifi

I need to turn on wifi and I find a lot of tutorials, but my try is without success - eg. http://aspyct.org/blog/2013/05/04/android-switch-wifi-on-off/

Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
```

And here is is code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false)
    {
        try
        {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I got this:
java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 10072

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent

Comment: The permissions look good at first glance. Might sound silly but try uninstalling and then re-installing your app. 
Sometimes permissions are a b*itch :
http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/01/31/fix-broken-android-permissions-by-re-installing-apps/

Comment: Yes, youre right. Reinstall of app makes different UID, but still the bad. It looks, that problem is in the device. So thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Narayan. Problem is really in the permissons of system. I cannot to solve it, but I know, that problem is in the device. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to suggest a package/installation issue. Maybe this a rooted device or maybe the app was installed in some unconventional way?

Kaamel

Comment: Not rooted device and app was installed from USB via apk installer.