# How to upload an image to server using android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to upload image binary.base64 convertion.but It will be working but the uploading time it will shows as below errors..so please anyone can a help me..

ERROR:////

LOG :

```
12-01 14:54:49.171 1304-1323/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: +5s269ms
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/25 from pid=3459, uid=10066 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
12-01 14:54:50.444 1694-1840/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
12-01 14:54:50.488 3459-3473/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-01 14:54:50.488 3459-3473/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeff6a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-01 14:54:50.658 3459-3473/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-01 14:54:50.659 3459-3473/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeff680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-01 14:54:53.968 3459-3473/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe97ab0
```

Comment: Did you consult this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent ?

Comment: requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, clearly says!

Comment: If you have targetSdkVersion 23 and you are using Android 6, you need to request the permissions at runtime: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html