# How to get access to my camera from my app in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, camera

I am creating a app. In this application I want to open my camera and I want to save it.

So I wrote code to do that

```
takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            count++;
            String file = dir+count+".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);

            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {

            }

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

        }
    });
```

and also i have added the permission to the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

But when I try to open the camera I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:
```

Why am I getting this since I have added the permissions

This is my error in the log

```
04-05 14:03:56.839 9562-9562/com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania, PID: 9562
                                                                                   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Selfimania/1.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{420a1c9 9562:com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania/u0a58} (pid=9562, uid=10058) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:162)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:925)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1008)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:940)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:929)
                                                                                       at com.example.pavithraprabodha.selfimania.Add_new_fragement$2.onClick(Add_new_fragement.java:89)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compileSdkVersion is less than 23, below marshmallow, you only need to define following permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you are saving the image or video then define the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission also.

Now for marshmallow you have to define permission dynamically ,something like this:

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERARESULT=201;

ibtn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if(getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ///method to get Images
                    takeVideo();
                }else{
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your Permission is needed to get access the camera",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERARESULT);
                }
            }else{
                takeVideo();
            }
        }
    });
```

In place of takeVideo u can use any method to open the camera, i have used

```
public void takeVideo(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    // 1- for high quality video
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // start the video capture Intent
    getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

}
```

To save the video to gallery you have to use a new intent with sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent) as shown above

if you are writing all this code inside feagment don't forgot to use context to call sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent) as getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)

check this:[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400554/saving-image-and-video-to-gallery-after-capturing-from-camera-without-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this answer

[Android: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: start Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent)

it is similar to your question,

Comment: actually the permissions are getting revoked

`revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA`

see the log