# Android Error:Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, permission-denied

I want to use `ActivityOptions` but When I try to run my application I am getting a security exception as

> Permission Denial:starting Intent.

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    options.setLaunchDisplayId(1);        
}
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
secondIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(secondIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Does anyone know what can i do for this?

Comment: Please post full error log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: start Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162447/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-start-intent)